# HTML -- How can I "stick" my navbar after reaching a specific section on page?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, navigation, sticky

I thought of 2 different methods to approaching this, but I need assistance.

1. Scroll to section and then stick.
2. Hide element while scrolling, then unhide element once you have reached point on page.

How can I do this?

I'm using [stickyjs](http://stickyjs.com/) currently.

But I don't see a feature for doing what I asked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m6q6j8xL/3/ header green is fixed and when you reach to blue div it will hide the header and show it when u come out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/m6q6j8xL/3/

this is custom js

in this demo the header changes to green(`fixed`) and when you reach to blue `div` changes back to `normal` and when u are out from the blue div it changes back to `fixed`

padding is added to div so that it doesn't effect window scroll when changed to fixed

```
var stickyNavTop = $('.header').offset().top;

function scrolling() {
    doc = $(document).height()
    hidingtop = $('.hiding').offset().top;
    hidingbottom = $('.hiding').position().top + $('.hiding').outerHeight(true) // finding the outer height
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > hidingtop && $(window).scrollTop() < hidingbottom) {
        $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.container').css('padding-top', '0');
    }
}

var stickyNav = function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
        $('.header').addClass('sticky');
        $('.container').css('padding-top', '100px');
    } else {
        $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.container').css('padding-top', '0');
    }
};

stickyNav();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    stickyNav();
    scrolling()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery-waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin for this.

[Demo](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/)

Comment: Thank you, very useful. Is there a demo posted anywhere utilizing only sticking at a certain point?