# Toggle class of sticky menu on scroll with overflow hidden on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to add a class `.custom-menu-bg` to sticky menu `.custom-menu` on scroll, while having `overflow: hidden` on body. Here's my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _rys = jQuery.noConflict();
  _rys("document").ready(function() {
    _rys(window).scroll(function() {
      if (_rys(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        _rys('.custom-menu').addClass("custom-menu-bg");
      } else {
        _rys('.custom-menu').removeClass("custom-menu-bg");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

But this code doesn't work with `overflow: hidden` on `body` tag
so I tried :

```
$('html').on('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  var delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
  if (delta < 0) {
    if ($('body').hasClass('section-element-1'))
      $('.custom-menu').addClass("custom-menu-bg");
  } else if (delta > 0) {
    $('.custom-menu').removeClass("custom-menu-bg");
  }
});
```

But this code only works for Mozilla and it's not a solution even, it's just a temp fix or work-around.

What I want is when I scroll down `$('.custom-menu').addClass("custom-menu-bg");` i.e. `custom-menu-bg` class gets added to `custom-menu`.

And when I scroll up to the top `$('.custom-menu').removeClass("custom-menu-bg");` i.e. `custom-menu-bg` class gets removed from `custom-menu`.

The top of `body`,`document`,`window` etcetera is always `0`.
And top of my `div` with class `custom-menu` also has `top: 0` always.

I'm looking for a permanent solution which works on all browsers.

Comment: how could you scroll when your `body { overflow: hidden; }` ?? Consider creating a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will help you and other SOusers to provide you a better solution.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466750/scrolling-element-without-scrollbar-with-css

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500923/html-how-can-i-stick-my-navbar-after-reaching-a-specific-section-on-page

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes I value your suggestion, but the link is of no use to me as I have a condition `body {overflow:hidden}`.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle or snippet so that i / other SO users can understand you issue it difficult to tell looking at only the js

Comment: yes we need a fiddle it's impossible to scroll a document with body in overflow hidden unless there is some other trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced the same effect you wanted [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/htmgkmqz/1/).

The only change that I've brought in comparison to your code is that I've made a *makeshift body `div`* and applied `overflow: hidden` on it.

Then, using jQuery, you'll be checking for the `scroll` event triggered by a *wrapper* inside the body `div` - which is in charge of holding the content) - and not by itself (or even `document`).

```
$('.wrapper').scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
          $('.custom-menu').addClass("custom-menu-bg");
      } else {
          $('.custom-menu').removeClass("custom-menu-bg");
      }
  });
```

This is because the makeshift body div has an `overflow` property set to `hidden`, and therefore won't generate that particular `scroll` event (*maybe it would if you had the handler registered using browser-specific scroll events*). Whereas the inner `wrapper` div will always have it's `height` property determined by it's content and is therefore *scrollable*.

**NOTE:** jQuery's `scroll()` is cross-browser, and hence a *permanent* solution.

Answer (score 1):

> You can bind on any id or on class also . its on you for now demo i
>   am using window .

**This single event works for both if you have scroll or not. i.e overflow:hidden or overflow:scroll**

```js
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        // scroll up
        $('.custom-menu').removeClass("custom-menu-bg");
    }
    else {
        // scroll down
      $('.custom-menu').addClass("custom-menu-bg");

    }
});
```

```css
.custom-menu {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}
.custom-menu-bg{
background-color: green;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-menu">

</div>
```

**Or you can also use this jQuery mousewheel plugin https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel.**

Answer (score 0):

//toggled is class when mobile menu is opened

```
let moveScroll  = '';    
window.onscroll = function (e) {    
   const navBar = document.getElementById('id-of-your-navigation-bar');    
    if (moveScroll > 0 && navBar.classList.contains('toggled')) {    
    navBar.classList.remove('toggled');    
    moveScroll = 0;       
  } else if (navBar.classList.contains('toggled')) {    
    moveScroll = 1;        
  }    
};
```