# show bootstrap banner at the top before navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I do have a bootstrap´ navbar at the very top of my page, this means that there is nothing above the navbar but now I would like to add a banner above the navbar and once the user scroll down the navbar got fixed in the top (that is not problem because is the actual behaviour) but I cannot get the banner at the top, it always appears after the navbar, this is the code of the navbar

```
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Texto", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li id="services">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Tipo de Evento", "TipoEvento", "Home")
                    </li>
                    <li id="other" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Ayuda<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("RecuperarClave", "Login")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Recuperar Contraseña</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contact")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Contactenos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Ayuda", "Home")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Manual de usuario</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

and this is the code of the banner I tried to locate before the navbar

```
<body>
    <header class="masthead">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="main-logo pull-left" href="#">Ribbit</a>
        </div>
    </header> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

but as I told you it always appears after the navbar, could you tell me what i have to do to show tha banner at the top?

Comment: Remove `.navbar-fixed-top`. Add it back when you scroll down your page past the header.

Comment: As mentioned, .navbar-fixed-top sets the nav element with a position: fixed causing this to have a fixed position at the top of your page regardless of the HTML markup sequence. You can nest your nav within the header and set the header to fixed position.

Comment: But if remove the .navbar-fixed-top if the user scrolls down the navbar dissapears and i don´t want the banner and the navbar to be fixed, only the navbar

Comment: That's why you need to do it dynamically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500923/html-how-can-i-stick-my-navbar-after-reaching-a-specific-section-on-page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a simplified example that works. Created a div with className banner above the Bootstrap navbar. The navbar does not have the 'fixed-top' class by default.

```
<div class="banner">
  <h1>Sample Banner</h1>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded" id="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>
```

Take advantage of jQuery since you're using Bootstrap. When the window has been scrolled all the way to the top the 'fixed-top' class will be removed from the navbar element. In all other instances it will be added to the navbar element.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $(".navbar").removeClass("fixed-top");
 } else {
    $(".navbar").addClass("fixed-top");
 }
});
```

Now when you scroll down the navbar gets fixed to the top. When you go back up to the top, it drops back under the main banner.

[Check out the CodePen for a live example](https://codepen.io/lookininward/pen/RgRmWj).